# How to add bootstrap glyphicon inside html.actionlink?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-3

Currently I am using bootstrap buttons for my following code and it is working fine:

```
    @Html.ActionLink("Bookmark this carpark!", "../Bookmarks/Create", new { carparkId = Model.id, address = Model.address }, new { @class = "btn btn-warning" })
```

However, I would like to also add in a glyphicon icon bookmark together. Any idea how do I do it ?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about other methods. But this is what i use.

`<a href="@Url.Action("Create", "Bookmarks")"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>Bookmark this carpark!</a>`